# How can I map one data to another while searching in database in Python

Tags: python, python-3.5

Ok so I was working on a project where have to search for an substring of an institute name, and the output should return all the institute name's with the input substring.

This is what I wrote,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

name = input("Enter the institute name : ")
flag = 0

with open('data.txt', 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        if (name.lower() in line.lower()):
            print (line)
            flag = 1

if(flag == 0):
    print("Sorry, the institute name you are trying to search does not exist in the database")
```

And my sample data looks like this:

```
IIT - M
Indian Institute of Technology, Madras
Indian Institute of Technology, Chennai
NIT - T
NIT - TIRCHY
NIT - TIRUCHIRANPPALLI
National Institute of Technology - Tiruchirannpalli
```

Note that IIT stands for Indian Institute of Technology and Madras and Chennai are 2 different names of the same city,NIT stands for National Institute of Technology whereas Tirchy and TIRUCHIRANPPALLI are same too.

Now I need help in implementing an algorithm which, for example if I input IIT the output comes as Indian Institute of Technology from the database.

Comment: One way or another you need a set of all equivalence classes of names. You could look into `fuzzywuzzy` package to match similar names, and then maybe merge some classes by hand / using an external reference.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  Specifically, give some examples of input and output, and include the code you've written to attempt the solution, as well as the actual output.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also applies, but you're quite close to that.

Comment: @Prune I think I have met the guidelines but thanks :)

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko yes I have read about fuzzywuzzy but a little more help would be appreciated. I am stuck on how to get outputs like Indian Institute of Technology from IIT.

Comment: For special cases like this, you could try going the other way, e.g. obtaining an acronym from a full name like so: `''.join(w[0] for w in name.split(' '))`. Still, getting your matching rate high really high is a difficult problem.

Comment: Do you have a large if not complete collection of associations between acronyms and the full names of the institutions?